# Get/set pricing template using androidpublisher inappproducts

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

I'm using the [`Inappproducts`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts) API for the Google Play Store.

My IAPs are all configured to use a [pricing template](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en).

> You can use pricing templates to setup or manage the same set of prices for multiple paid apps and in-app products. If you update a pricing template, all items linked to the template will use the template’s latest prices.

For each IAP, I would like to view and/or edit its pricing template.

I can't see any way to do this with the API. The API returns a `defaultPrice` and an array of localized `prices`, but I don't see a way to view which template is in use, or any way to link these IAPs to a pricing template using the API.

Is this possible? Is there another way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this can't be managed using the API.

However, if all you want to do is update a bunch of price templates in bulk, you can do this with CSV import/export on the IAP page in the Google Play Console. (You have to manually login to initiate the export, modify the templates, and then re-import.)

Go to the "In-app products" page of the "Monetize" section for your app. There are "Import" and "Export" buttons in the top right. When you export a CSV, it has a "Pricing Template ID" column which you can edit and re-import.

Comment: Where do you see the option to import/export a price template on Google Play Console? Can't see it in the old and new GUI of the Play Console.

Comment: Can't see the option either, I've been waiting for it for years, always manually entering all pricing, such a pain!

Comment: @0101100101 I added a bit more detail to my answer.

Comment: Right, for in app-products yes, but it doesn't exist when modifying subscriptions or pricing templates, which is quite ridiculous.